# Is there any way, in javascript, to obtain the name of the function, inside the function which was called

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the name of the currently running function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)
>   [Get function name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178892/get-function-name-in-javascript)

Is there any way, in javascript, to obtain the name of the function, inside the function which was called.

```
function something() {
   console.log( "The name of the function you invoke is " ...should says 'something' );
}
```

Comment: This very same question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

yes.

```
function something(){
    alert(arguments.callee.name);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in among others MSIE and it's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee