# javascript - Get name of function through a function

Tags: javascript

So say, I have function `Hello_world()` :

```
function Hello_world() {
  b();
}
```

I want to create function `b()` where `b()` returns the name of the function in which called it. In this case I want `b()` returns `"Hello_world"`.

So how should `b()` be constructed? Thx.

Comment: No, you don't want that. [What problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Try use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178892/get-function-name-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use three [despised](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee), [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) and [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) properties for this:

```
function b() {
    return arguments.callee.caller.name;
}
```

Don't expect it to work in older browsers, newer browsers, strict mode, internet explorer, …

Comment: +1 I was not aware of it.  if it a non-standard can we pass the method name as a parameter to `b(theCallerName){ return theCallerName}`?

Comment: Yes, you can and should, though it makes `b()` superfluous :-)

Comment: @Praveen—hopefully you'd pass a reference to the function, rather than just its name. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: Actually I meant passing the name as a string is the best solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a trick with the stack trace, which is also despised (since it's highly platform-dependent) and ugly to say the least:

```
function getStackTrace() { return new Error().stack; }
```

Which would return something like this in chrome's developer's console:

```
"Error
    at getStackTrace (<anonymous>:2:35)
    at <anonymous>:2:1
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:581:39)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:540:52)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:459:21)"
```

and you go with reqular expressions from there.

Will work in Chrome, not sure for others, so it's bad for production-versions. Nice hack though :)