# How to get variable name in annonymous function construnction var f = function(){};

Tags: javascript, servicenow

So I have a construction like below (this is dummy code).
Inside of function assigned to someFunction variable I'd like to get actual name of variable that this function is assigned to.

Expected result of return would be string "someFunction".

Thank you for your expertise!

I've tried this; and have no other clue yet.

```
var someFunction = (function(){
 "use strict"; 
var f = this.FunctionName; //dummy code
return f;
}
```

expected to have "someFunction" string as return

```
var onLoad_123123= (function(GlideAjax,g_form,GlideDialogWindow,GlideRecord,window,document,$,jQuery,$$,$j,$F,gel,undefined){
 "use strict"; 
function onLoad_123123() {
    retun 'onLoad_123123'; //dummy code here - have to get it dynamically
}
```

Hope that explains it better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get function name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178892/get-function-name-in-javascript)

Comment: I can provide examples that demonstrate why this is a weird question, but before I do that I'd like to know which problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: I don't think it's possible - also, your IIFE is invalid (missing `)()`)

Comment: @charlietfl: `return someFunction.name;` would work, but of course that just returns `"someFunction"`, so they might as well write `return "someFunction";`.

Comment: @JackBashford: I don't think it's supposed to be an IIFE, since they say *"Inside of function assigned to someFunction"*.

Comment: @FelixKling will only work in non-strict mode tho. We could use `arguments.callee.name` if we were not in strict mode, which would exactly fulfi the requirement.

Comment: It looks like an IIFE though

Comment: @jAndy: Why should that only work in non-strict mode? *edit:* `arguments.callee.name` only works in non-strict mode, yes. But `someFunction.name` works anywhere (but is pointless).

Comment: @FelixKling `callee` and `caller` properties are prohibited in strict mode and will throw an error on access. I thought you were suggesting the same, because as you already mentioned, `someFunction.name` is pretty pointless.

Comment: @jAndy: Hence my first comment ("examples that demonstrate why this is a weird question") :)

Comment: A mandatory reminder: it's OP's responsibility to share their problem not the community's to guess. I know you're good at guessing, but still ;-P

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you need the function name. It's not quite clear which code is your own and which comes from the platform/service you are using.

Comment: Edited question. Maybe that will help you understand what is needed. Appreciate your help

Comment: No, it does not explain why you need the function name.

Comment: @FelixKling Are you familiar with ServiceNOW? If not, your help and comments won't be needed anymore.

Comment: Good luck finding people who want to help with that attitude. Answering a simple question would be so much more productive than attacking others, especially considering that you want something from us.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get and return a function name "*dynamically*"
is to access 
`arguments.callee.name` from within the function.

> This won't be available in strict mode. If you declare a function
>   as strict, your interpreter will throw on error when you try to access
>   that property.

Comment: It is inside of ServiceNOW - don't have influence on that use strict; line - need other solution

Comment: "need other solution" --- or better, other design.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other solution. The access to those properties `callee` and `caller` were removed on introducing strict mode (for good security reasons).
As @zerkms mentioned, you should reconsider whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: note also that `const foo = function() { console.log(arguments.callee.name); }; foo(); // logs foo` but `const foo = () => { console.log(arguments.callee.name); }; foo(); // Error: arguments is not defined`

Comment: @zerkms very helpful - tell it to servicenow.com

Comment: @wojasso what is really "helpful" - is not sharing a problem details for half an hour then wondering why you did not get the answer you want.

Comment: In conclusion. Using `use strict;`
and trying to retrieve function name is not possible at all? So now to ServiceNOW experts. Is it possible in any other way to retrieve Client Script sys_id / Client Script name or any other identifier within its script body?

Comment: @zerkms I don't think you can be more helpful than you've been so far - please use your time to answer on other questions. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know "use strict" isn't enabled in serviceNow. So try this:

```
console.log("internal id: " + arguments.callee.name);
console.log("internal sysId: " + g_event_handler_ids[arguments.callee.name]);
```

g_event_handler_ids holds all scripts for the catalog item.