# Get the name of ES6 class method

Tags: javascript, es6-class

When I am printing helpful errors in my program, I want to print along the method name. So for example in the mock code below when console logging inside `goodMorning`, I want to embed the name 'goodMorning' or 'Hello.goodMorning' in the print out by calling a `getMethodName` function; the function now simply returns 'goodMorning' but I want it to return the name of whatever method it is called in (it may need to take some argument to do that).

```
const getMethodName = () => {
    return 'goodMorning'
}

class Hello {
  goodMorning () {
    console.log(`I am inside ${getMethodName()} method`)
  }
}

new Hello().goodMorning()
```

Comment: It is usually better to use `console.trace` (or other `console` methods that also provide stack) or `debugger` to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get function name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178892/get-function-name-in-javascript)

Comment: @sibabratswain not it doesn't answer my question. The solutions suggested there doesn't work for ES6 class methods.

Comment: @user120242 I see an answer posted there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27462108/10654418) that also partly answers this question. But I am looking for a much better answer for ES6 class methods, not just for a classless function.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what u r asking for

```js
const getMethodName = () => {
  var functionName = new Error().stack.match(/at (.*?) /);
  return functionName[1]
}

class Hello {
  goodMorning() {
    console.log(`I am inside ${getMethodName()} method`)
  }
}

new Hello().goodMorning();
```

Better u can directly try capturing error without calling to any specific function

Comment: Thank you. `console.log(`I am inside ${new Error().stack.match(/at (.*?) /)[1]} method`)` seems to work, but I wish there was a more elegant solution

Comment: FYI the function she's asking for is actually the calling method, not the helper function, so the regex you want is actually `new Error().stack.match(/at .*?\n.*? at (.*?) /)` to get the second function in the call stack (the caller).

Comment: Yes, `const getMethodName = () => new Error().stack.match(/at .*?\n.*? at (.*?) /)[1]` does exactly what I am looking for. This will do for now. Thanks once again.

Comment: @faint-hearted-fool this has some browser compatibility issues apparently.  Please see dupe link for more information: specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47812770/120242