# Get the wrapping function name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

How can I get the wrapping function name of my code? I want to implement a runtime-tracking feature in many functions of my project and don't want to replace the function name in every function by myself.

```
function my_function_name() {
  let t0 = performance.now();
  ....
  DEBUG_TRACK_RUNTIME(performance.now() - t0)
}

function DEBUG_TRACK_RUNTIME(runtime) {
  console.log("PROCESS RUNTIME: " + this.caller, Math.round(runtime, 0) + " ms")
}
```

Is there a way to get the function name "my_function_name()" as a string?

---

QUESTION ANSWERED. This solution worked great for me. Thanks

```
function abcd() {
    let t0 = performance.now();
    ...
    DEBUG_TRACK_RUNTIME(arguments.callee.name, performance.now() - t0)
}

function DEBUG_TRACK_RUNTIME(title, runtime) {
    console.log("PROCESS RUNTIME: " + title + "()", Math.round(runtime, 0) + " ms")
}
```

Comment: duplicate: [Get function name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178892/get-function-name-in-javascript)

Comment: Maybe you should not build complex generic reusable features based on `arguments.callee`. It won't work in strict mode. In modern browsers JS code is always run in strict mode in modules and class declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`arguments.calle.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee):

```js
function my_function_name() {
  console.log(arguments.callee.name);
}

my_function_name();
```

Comment: Won't work in strict mode, though.

Comment: Is there a proper way?